# Clarification on changed rules of getting rating from FIDE

Tags: rules, rating

As of July 2014 FIDE states

7.14c
The condition of a minimum of 5 games need not be met in one tournament. Results from other tournaments played within consecutive rating periods totalling not more than 26 months, are pooled to obtain the initial rating.

Before July 2014, 12 months period of play for minimum of 9 games was pooled together to calculate the rating, and if minimum of 9 games are not played within 12 months then you are supposed to play 9 more games again starting as a new unrated player.

Well i had played 8 rated games before June 2014 (in April and I'm still unrated because i did not play the the 9th one) and now as 12 months has passed as per the old rule but not 26 months as per new one, if i play a FIDE rated tournament now, will the performance of my last tournament be considered for my rating performance or do i have to play freshly at least 5 games and get 0.5 points to get a new rating.

Answer (score 2):

If at least 4 of your opponents in that April 2014 FIDE rated tournament had FIDE ratings before the tournament and if you play another FIDE rated player in another FIDE rated tournament within 26 months of the April 2014 tournament and if you scored at least half a point out of all the games you played against FIDE rated opponents (so minimum of 0.5 / 5) then you should get a FIDE rating.

The key points are that you have to play at least 5 FIDE rated opponents (some of your opponents in April 2014 may have been unrated like you) and you have to get at least one draw against your FIDE rated opponents. They can't calculate a rating if you lose all your games.

Comment: All 8 of my opponents were rated and I've scored 6 out of it. So according to new rule i should already had gotten the rating.. But at the time i played the rules were different as I've mentioned in the question.